# Can a steak be deep fried in clarified butter?

Tags: butter, steak, deep-frying

Steaks can be deep fried and this is usually done with an oil with a high smoke point. People seem to report reasonably good results with this.

I'd like to deep fry with butter as this would impart that butter flavour. Using un-clarified butter would lead to a smoke show (I think), but clarified butter should get hot enough without smoking too much.

Would it be possible to deep fry a steak in clarified butter?

If so, can the clarified butter be recuperated and used again?

If so, could the clarified butter be infused with garlic or thyme some how?

Answer (score 6):

I haven't tried it personally, so this is purely hypothetical. Clarified butter has a smoke point of 252 degrees Celsius, which is well above the temperature one would use to deep fry anything. So deep frying in clarified butter should be possible. I would not however try to infuse the butter with anything. Infusing it would mean adding oils from herbs or garlic with a much lower smoke point, which would probably make the end result taste burned.

Comment: This is what I am thinking as well. Hopefully someone has tried it and can comment. Do you know if the butter could be cooled and stored and used again?

Comment: I would think another caution against infusing would be the same as attempts to infuse olive oil.  Things like garlic and fresh herbs would be botulism risk by providing a potential air free environment for potentially introduced spores.

Comment: Goose grease might make for a tasty alternative.